# Lambda (connected with Kinesis Data Stream) function generating cloudwatch logs continuously

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-rekognition

In my current project, my objective is to detect different objects from a Stream of Frames. The video frames are captured using camera, connected with the Raspberry PI.

The following is a rough architecture.
[image]

The architecture design is as follows:

- `video_cap.py` code is running on raspberry PI. This code sends a stream of images to the **Kinesis Data Stream** (called it `FrameStream`) in AWS.
- The `FrameStream` Data Stream receives the stream and trigger to a **lambda function** (named `lambda_function.py`) . The lambda function is written using `Python 3.7`.

This lambda function receives streams of images, and trigger AWS Rekognition and sends an email notification.

**My problem is even if I stop (by pressing `Ctrl + C`) ( `video_cap.py` python file, running on raspberry PI), the lambda function keep writing logs (reporting old received frames) into CloudWatch.**

Please help me - how can I fix this issues? Please let me know if you need any additional information.

`video_cap.py` file code

```
# Copyright 2017 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
# Licensed under the Amazon Software License (the "License"). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the License is located at
#     http://aws.amazon.com/asl/
# or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

import sys
import cPickle
import datetime
import cv2
import boto3
import time
import cPickle
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pytz

kinesis_client = boto3.client("kinesis")
rekog_client = boto3.client("rekognition")

camera_index = 0 # 0 is usually the built-in webcam
capture_rate = 30 # Frame capture rate.. every X frames. Positive integer.
rekog_max_labels = 123
rekog_min_conf = 50.0

#Send frame to Kinesis stream
def encode_and_send_frame(frame, frame_count, enable_kinesis=True, enable_rekog=False, write_file=False):
    try:
        #convert opencv Mat to jpg image
        #print "----FRAME---"
        retval, buff = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)

        img_bytes = bytearray(buff)

        utc_dt = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
        now_ts_utc = (utc_dt - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()

        frame_package = {
            'ApproximateCaptureTime' : now_ts_utc,
            'FrameCount' : frame_count,
            'ImageBytes' : img_bytes
        }

        if write_file:
            print("Writing file img_{}.jpg".format(frame_count))
            target = open("img_{}.jpg".format(frame_count), 'w')
            target.write(img_bytes)
            target.close()

        #put encoded image in kinesis stream
        if enable_kinesis:
            print "Sending image to Kinesis"
            response = kinesis_client.put_record(
                StreamName="FrameStream",
                Data=cPickle.dumps(frame_package),
                PartitionKey="partitionkey"
            )
            print response

        if enable_rekog:
            response = rekog_client.detect_labels(
                Image={
                    'Bytes': img_bytes
                },
                MaxLabels=rekog_max_labels,
                MinConfidence=rekog_min_conf
            )
            print response

    except Exception as e:
        print e


def main():

    argv_len = len(sys.argv)

    if argv_len > 1 and sys.argv[1].isdigit():
        capture_rate = int(sys.argv[1])

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #Use 0 for built-in camera. Use 1, 2, etc. for attached cameras.
    pool = Pool(processes=3)

    frame_count = 0
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        #cv2.resize(frame, (640, 360));

        if ret is False:
            break

        if frame_count % capture_rate == 0:
            result = pool.apply_async(encode_and_send_frame, (frame, frame_count, True, False, False,))

        frame_count += 1

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Lambda function (`lambda_function.py`)

```
from __future__ import print_function

import base64
import json
import logging
import _pickle as cPickle
#import time
from datetime import datetime
import decimal
import uuid
import boto3
from copy import deepcopy

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) 
rekog_client = boto3.client('rekognition')

# S3 Configuration
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_bucket = "bucket-name-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
s3_key_frames_root = "frames/"

# SNS Configuration
sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
label_watch_sns_topic_arn = "SNS-ARN-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 

#Iterate on rekognition labels. Enrich and prep them for storage in DynamoDB
labels_on_watch_list = []
labels_on_watch_list_set = []
text_list_set = []

# List for detected text
text_list = []

def process_image(event, context):

    # Start of for Loop
    for record in event['Records']:
        frame_package_b64 = record['kinesis']['data']
        frame_package = cPickle.loads(base64.b64decode(frame_package_b64))

        img_bytes = frame_package["ImageBytes"]

        approx_capture_ts = frame_package["ApproximateCaptureTime"]
        frame_count = frame_package["FrameCount"]

        now_ts = datetime.now()

        frame_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        approx_capture_timestamp = decimal.Decimal(approx_capture_ts)

        year = now_ts.strftime("%Y")
        mon = now_ts.strftime("%m")
        day = now_ts.strftime("%d")
        hour = now_ts.strftime("%H")

        #=== Object Detection from an Image =====

        # AWS Rekognition - Label detection from an image
        rekog_response = rekog_client.detect_labels(
            Image={
                'Bytes': img_bytes
            },
            MaxLabels=10,
            MinConfidence= 90.0
        )

        logger.info("Rekognition Response" + str(rekog_response) )

        for label in rekog_response['Labels']:
            lbl = label['Name']
            conf = label['Confidence']
            labels_on_watch_list.append(deepcopy(lbl)) 

        labels_on_watch_list_set = set(labels_on_watch_list)

        #print(labels_on_watch_list)
        logger.info("Labels on watch list ==>" + str(labels_on_watch_list_set) )

            # Vehicle Detection
            #if (lbl.upper() in (label.upper() for label in ["Transportation", "Vehicle", "Van" , "Ambulance" , "Bus"]) and conf >= 50.00):
                #labels_on_watch_list.append(deepcopy(label))

        #=== Detecting text from a detected Object
        # Detect text from the detected vehicle using detect_text()
        response=rekog_client.detect_text( Image={ 'Bytes': img_bytes })
        textDetections=response['TextDetections']
        for text in textDetections:
            text_list.append(text['DetectedText']) 

        text_list_set = set(text_list)   
        logger.info("Text Detected ==>" + str(text_list_set))

    # End of for Loop

    # SNS Notification
    if len(labels_on_watch_list_set) > 0 :
        logger.info("I am in SNS Now......")
        notification_txt = 'On {} Vehicle was spotted with {}% confidence'.format(now_ts.strftime('%x, %-I:%M %p %Z'), round(label['Confidence'], 2))
        resp = sns_client.publish(TopicArn=label_watch_sns_topic_arn,
            Message=json.dumps( 
                {
                    "message": notification_txt + " Detected Object Categories " + str(labels_on_watch_list_set) + " " + " Detect text on the Object " + " " + str(text_list_set)
                }
            ))

    #Store frame image in S3
    s3_key = (s3_key_frames_root + '{}/{}/{}/{}/{}.jpg').format(year, mon, day, hour, frame_id)
    s3_client.put_object(
        Bucket=s3_bucket,
        Key=s3_key,
        Body=img_bytes
    )

    print ("Successfully processed  records.")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Successfully processed  records.')
    }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   logger.info("Received event from Kinesis ......" )
   logger.info("Received event ===>" + str(event))
   return process_image(event, context)
```

Lambda permission
[image]

The following is IAM policy attached with the Lambda role.
[image]

The following is the Kinesis Data Stream Log (**Dated 17th August, 2019 - 1:54 PM IST**). The last time, the data ingested through Raspberry PI on **16th August, 2019 - 6:45 PM**)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set the number of shards correctly? It is likely that the streaming data will be buffered if the number of shards not optimised, resulting in this behavior.  number_of_shards = max (incoming_write_bandwidth_in_KB/1000, outgoing_read_bandwidth_in_KB/2000)

Comment: @erhanux : thanks for the response.  The currently, the stream has 1 shard.  Let me  try to increase the value.

Comment: The  same problem.  The Data stream is logging the old stream value. It does not take the new stream.

Comment: Check CloudWatch metrics, in case you spot something. Good luck. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch.html

Comment: If your function returns an error the Lambda retries until processing succeeds or the data expires.   Lambda's generally don't need to return a value to indicate a success.  I would try removing your return statement:    

return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Successfully processed  records.')
    }

Comment: @WaltDe : Thanks for the suggestions.  As per AWS Lambda documentation, ` return` statement sends the success / failure response. Thus, it does not affect the overall stream. however, I have removed `return`. Still, the problem remains the same. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: @WaltDe : Can we flush the Data Stream content programmatically ? For instance, once the stream is stop, a Kinesis stream can be  flushed the all previous content.  This way, the stream may stop logging??? Any thoughts on it??

Comment: @Pankesh I don't know a way to easily flush the stream, but you can drop the retention period down to a minimum of 24 hours which is the default.  Go to the Kinesis Streams Dashboard.  Select your stream and choose (Actions-> Details) scroll down the page and you will see "Data retention period" which you can edit.

The other way I can think of is to delete the stream and create it again.   If you are not using something like CloudFormation or Terraform now is a good time to start.

Comment: @Pankesh Actually, one way to clear the stream is to create Lambda that just acknowledge the events.  Take a look a the [Example index.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis-example.html) in this easy tutorial.  Just remove decode and print of the payload since you dealing with video.  The other benefit of doing this is to confirm you have everything else working and you have a python lambda issue.

Comment: @WaltDe : The retention of Kinesis Data Stream  is 24 hours in my current setting. I delete Kinesis Data Stream and re-create data stream. The newly created stream gets the new stream. But, after some streaming, the problem remains the same.

Comment: @WaltDe: In  my current implementation, I have been printing the payload (and see them in CloudWatch) to confirm everything is working. It seems that there is a problem in Kinesis Data Stream.   Let me try to slow the framerate at which the raspberry PI is pushing data to Kinesis using `time.sleep(1)` function and see the result, if any changes.

Comment: @Pankesh Take a look at the monitoring tab.  Look at your "Get Records (Count) - Sum" and "Incoming Data (Count) -Sum"  You are looking to see if the Get Count is keeping up with Incoming Count.  If not, then you need to shard.  Also, check that "Get Records Success (Percent) — Average" is 100%.

Comment: @WaltDe: I have attached Kinesis Data Stream Log for your reference (in the question). It may help you to see more detail.                The Kinesis Data Stream Log is**Dated 17th August, 2019 - 1:54 PM IST**). The last time, the data ingested through Raspberry PI on **16th August, 2019 - 6:45 PM IST** )  Please let me know, if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have about 117K records in the stream but slowly processing 1 records at time.  How long does it take the lambda to process one record?  I would get how long your lambda runs , update the python put code to sleep a little longer the lambda runs (start with 20% longer), then restart with an empty queue, and watch the stats in real time.